# Reading from the text file using Buffered Reader

Tags: java, bufferedreader, flat

I am attempting to read from a text file, 
I am using try and resource block to read from the flat file:

```
ABC 24 32
1234567
2345678
3456789
CDE 25 35
4567890
5678901
```

I want the output so:

```
ABC, 1234567
ABC, 2345678
ABC, 3456789
CDE, 4567890
CDE, 5678901
```

I tried research using `mark()` and `reset()`. 
Any suggestions would be of great help

```
public static void advParse(String fileName){

        File file = new File("test1.txt");
        ArrayList<Head> abc = new ArrayList<Head>();

        try( BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))){
            Head head = new Head();
            String line ;

            while(((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)){

                while(line.length()==7 ){

                 System.out.println(line);




        } 
            }
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found for  "+file.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Unable to the read the file "+file.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        };


}
```

Comment: You "tried research", but have you tried writing any actual code? We have to take your word that you have put effort into this, why not show us what you've done so we can *see* the effort you have put into it.

Comment: Here's a suggestion: Post what you've already tried that has problems, tell us what problems you are having, and we can assist you

Comment: what exactly isn't working?

Comment: You will need to use a variable to remember the most recently read alphabetic line.  Testing whether a line consists of alphabetic characters is best done with a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: Why haven't you stepped through this in your debugger?

Answer (score 0):

your line second line in a file `1234567` which length is 7 and you have this inner loop:

```
while(line.length()==7 ){
  System.out.println(line);
}
```

so I would assume it iterates forever. 
Maybe change it with `if` clause